# GridView: Attempt to invoke virtual method.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a `ListView` and I'm trying to go to `GridView` OnItemCLiclick listener. I have an exception on the adapter put I can't solve it.

The list view is a fragment and it works very well!

The exception is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup)' on a null object reference
>                                                                   at com.rt_no.myprogect.ui.adapter.CareerImageAdapter.getView(CareerImageAdapter.java:52)

at this line in the `GridView` adapter:

```
convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.career_grid_view, null);
```

**The ListView:**

```
public class CitiesFragment extends Fragment   {
    private static final String TAG ="CitiesFragment";

    private ListView cityList;
    private ArrayList<City> cities;
    private CitiesAdapter citiesAdapter;
    private CitiesFragmentListener listener;

    private Context context;

    private GridView gridView;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Log.d(TAG, "onAttach_CitiesFragment");
        listener = (CitiesFragmentListener) context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView_CitiesFragment");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cities_list_view_fragment, null);
        return view;
    }

    private ArrayList<City> initCities(){.....}

    private void initGridView(Fragment fragment){
        Log.d(TAG, "CitiesFragment_initGridView");
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragment");
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated_CitiesFragment");
        cities = initCities();
        cityList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.cityList);
        citiesAdapter = new CitiesAdapter(getActivity(), cities);
        cityList.setAdapter(citiesAdapter);
        cityList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick_CitiesFragment position : " + cities.get(position).getCityName());
                GridViewFragment fragment = new GridViewFragment();
                initGridView(fragment);
            }
        });
    }
```

**The GridView:**

```
public class GridViewFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "GridViewFragment";

    private CitiesFragmentListener listener;
    private GridView gridView;
    private CareerImageAdapter careerImageAdapter;
    private int position;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView_GridViewFragment");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.career_grid_view, null);
        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.careerGridView);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated_GridViewFragment");
        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.careerGridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(new CareerImageAdapter(getActivity()));
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick_GridViewFragment position : " + position);

                // go to workers_list_view_fragment layout

            }
        });
    }
```

**The GridView Adapter:**

```
public class CareerImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "CareerImageAdapter";

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

     public CareerImageAdapter (Context c){
         mContext = c;
     }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ImageIdes.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CareerImageAdapter getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView ;

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.career_grid_view, null);
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(180, 180));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_END);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(ImageIdes[position]);
        return convertView;
    }

    private Integer[] ImageIdes =
            {
                R.drawable.afar,R.drawable.asbaka,R.drawable.bnya,
                R.drawable.cnstractors,R.drawable.doors,R.drawable.etom,
                R.drawable.floring,R.drawable.foxy,R.drawable.garnolet,
                R.drawable.gaz,R.drawable.geves,R.drawable.ginoon,
                R.drawable.halbashateven,R.drawable.hashmal,R.drawable.instltsya,
                R.drawable.kvesatshatyah,R.drawable.mazgan,R.drawable.meshlowah,
                R.drawable.pargolot,R.drawable.pegom,R.drawable.pinoyafpa,
                R.drawable.robah,R.drawable.tyah,
            };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`layoutInflater` is never initialized. Add this in the `CareerImageAdapter` constructor:

`layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);`

Comment: thank you very much. i was do it, i have another exception the casting of the :
`        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
`     i set :  `imageView = (ImageView) convertView.getTag();`  ithe exception is :`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference` it's  of the line : `        imageView.setImageResource(ImageIdes[position]);
`

Comment: If it helped, please mark it as answered. About your other crash, you can't do that cast. You need to review your adapter. Here is an example https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html. Also, I suggest to use RecyclerView instead of the old GridView.

Comment: i have another Exception if you can help me?